# Xamarin.Android Splash Screen Size

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I've got a splash screen problem where I've got a simple logo I'd like to be roughly in the center of the screen. For some reason, the drawable I have is taking up the whole screen, and won't center my image neatly in the center. I've heard of 9-patch images, but I'm not sure if that's applicable to this (I think this is for icons?). Anyway, here is what I have for a drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/orangey_red"/>

  <item android:gravity="center">
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I also have a theme defined for this drawable. Here is /values/style.xml

```
<resources>
 <style name="MyCustomTheme" >
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_drawable</item>
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

I'm using Xamarin.Android (native), and cannot figure this problem out.

Comment: 9-patch images is not suitable for this case. I am not sure what do you mean about `won't center my image neatly in the center`, I think it is better to give a picture for you result and what do you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It seems that my logo size was too big for the screen, so resizing the image to a smaller resolution was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works well on my side, here is the style:

```
  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
```

And here is the splash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/orangey_red"/>

  <item android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/dapao"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I also provide my demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/SplashCenter), you can compare your project with it.